# How to add Attribute Tagged Value using C#

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I am trying to create an EA Attribute and after that I am adding Tagged Value to that attribute.

The problem is when I create the tagged value for the attribute without any value then its creating fine with proper Type but when I fill some value into the tagged then the Type of the tagged value is changing.

```
EA.Attribute headerName = eleName.Attributes.AddNew("Header", "char");
headerName.Update();

EA.AttributeTag decAtt = headerName.TaggedValues.AddNew("Description", "<memo>");
decAtt.Update();
decAtt.Value = "Description needs to entered";
```

How to add the Tagged values for the attribute without changing the properties ?

How to add the contents to  Tagged values note through Adddin ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
EA.Attribute headerName = eleName.Attributes.AddNew("Header", "char");
headerName.Update();

EA.AttributeTag decAtt = headerName.TaggedValues.AddNew("Description","");
decAtt.Value = "<memo>";
decAtt.Notes = "Description needs to be entered";
decAtt.Update();
```

PS. I'm surprised the `Attributes.AddNew("Header", "char")` works for you. I would never trust the AddNew operation to define the type of my attributes.

Comment: The Help tells that the 2nd parameter is "Type" which varies in the context. This of course is explained nowhere (one could find). Though "Type" and Attribute.Type seem to match.